# Scheduled import .MDB file from ftp server into MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, import, export

I need a little help with scheduled export/import, the situation:

I need to import a .MDB file stored on an ftp into a MySQL server, scheduled. 
Whats the best way to go about this?

Do I export from Acces to CSV (how would i schedule this?) and export that to a ftp server? Or write the DMB to a server convert it there and schedule import on mysql?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with writing an SSIS package that takes source data from FTP server (access files) and import them into the MySQL RDBMS. If you need this to be done regularly, schedule this a db job in the db server which can fire the SSIS package at regular intervals.

ps: I know this is a very late response.